# or.rename(src,dest) throws file is not error in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I try to rename a file remotely in my sftp server.
Here is my code smaple;

```
 srv = pysftp.Connection(host=host, username=username, password=password, port=port, cnopts=connOption)
    # Get the directory and file listing
    data = srv.listdir()

    try:
        for infile in data:
            if infile == filename:
                infile_without_ext = os.path.splitext(infile)[0]
                extension = os.path.splitext(infile)[1]
                new_file_name = infile_without_ext + "_" + str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
                new_file_name_with_ext = new_file_name + extension

                print infile   //<----printing the file
                print new_file_name_with_ext

                os.rename(infile,  new_file_name_with_ext)
```

When I print `infile` it prints file. But when I try to rename I get error;

```
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

My file is in the root directory.
How can I solve this?

Comment: Why are you trying to rename a file on *your* computer instead of *theirs*?

Comment: @user2357112 I need to rename the file in sftpserver, else it will be overwritten( not relevant to my original question)

Comment: But you've used `os.rename` instead of `srv.rename` or anything to do with your SFTP connection.

Comment: And `//` is not for comments in Python.

Comment: Check if the `//` is an issue. It's used for division. Try to comment it out with # and see your code works. Also try `os.rename` with `filename` instead of `infile`

Comment: @user2357112 do you have any clue on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55682609/moving-file-in-sftp-server-using-python

Answer (score -1):

You can refer to the source code：

```
    def rename(self, remote_src, remote_dest):
    """rename a file or directory on the remote host.

    :param str remote_src: the remote file/directory to rename

    :param str remote_dest: the remote file/directory to put it

    :returns: None

    :raises: IOError

    """
    self._sftp_connect()
    self._sftp.rename(remote_src, remote_dest)
```

Comment: Might help to explain what's going on in this code.