# Moving file in sftp server using python throws exception

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have successfully connected to the SFTP server and can download files. But when I try to move a file from one location to another in my SFTP location, I get `file already exist` error. But It is not there (I check using Filezilla).

My currentFolder structure

```
/
--2019-01
--2019-02
--2019-03
--2019-04
-test_2019_04_15 10:01:01.fil
```

Code

```
def moveRawfile(serverConn, newFile):
    system_date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m")
    folder_name = str(system_date)
    path = '/'
    try :
        serverConn.chdir(folder_name)
    except IOError as e:
        serverConn.mkdir(folder_name, mode=777)

    path = os.path.join(path, folder_name)
    try :
        newpath = os.path.join(path, newFile)
        serverConn.rename(newFile, newpath)  //<______This throws error(File already existing)
    except IOError as e:
        raise e
```

> newpath=/2019-04/test_2019_04_15 10:01:01.fil
>
> newFile=test_2019_04_15 10:01:01.fil

I try to move this file to `2019_04` folder.
The folder is there. But when I try to move the file, It says it is already existing.
I couldn't figure out what is wrong in my code.

Comment: You can't rename to an existing filename, just like any other operating system will either reject a similarly named file or prompt to overwrite.

Delete the old file first, then move the new file to that name.

Comment: @RetroCraft My issue is that. I dont have file under '/2019-04' folder. I try to move the file to that location

Answer (score 0):

The error response I get doesn't provide detail info about the actual issue.

I solved this issue , by adding '/' to the source file.

eg:  `serverConn.rename('/'+newFile, newpath)`